# Sumproduct with Three Criteria and

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to figure out how to search the for the left most character in a cell, which will always be 1 or 2, and then search for a short string, like ‘Flow’ inside of a longer string, like ‘System Flow’ or ‘Flow Control’, and if those two criteria are met, then take an average of the numbers in the corresponding rows, in Column M.  So, this is the third criteria.  I came up with the function below, but it always returns 0, which is not correct.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(K38:K44,1)=C38)*(ISNUMBER(FIND(D38,L38:L44))))*M38:M44
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong here?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use AVERAGEIFS():

```
=AVERAGEIFS(M38:M44,K38:K44,C38 & "*",L38:L44,"*" & D38 & "*")
```

---

Edit, to deal with the change of numbers and strings we need to adjust your formula a bit:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(K38:K44,1)=TEXT(C38,"@"))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D38,L38:L44)))*M38:M44)/SUMPRODUCT((LEFT(K38:K44,1)=TEXT(C38,"@"))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D38,L38:L44))))
```

Comment: That looks very promising, but the wildcard range is K38:K44 and L38:L44.  The C38 is a 2 and the D83 has 'Flow'.  I tried to adjust your formula accordingly, but I keep getting a #DIV/0! error.

Comment: Did you try the formula as is?

Comment: This formula will look like this: `=AVERAGEIFS(M38:M44,K38:K44,"2*",L38:L44,"*Flow*")`  Which means that if K starts with 2 and flow is found in L then use M in the average. @ryguy72

Comment: Apparently the problem is coming from the wildcards.  This doesn't work:  
=AVERAGEIFS(M38:M44,K38:K44,"1*",L38:L44,"*Flow*")  This does work: =AVERAGEIFS(M38:M44,K38:K44,"1",L38:L44,"Flow"), but then I have to have only a 1 in K38:K44 and only Flow in L38:L44.

Comment: That is correct, it is expecting more. It will not find `1` = `"1"`.  See edit for a rework of your equation.

Comment: Yeay!  The sumproduct function works now.  Thanks so much!!

Comment: @ryguy72 please remember to mark as correct by clicking the check mark.

Comment: Yes sir!  I just did it.  Thanks again.

Comment: @ryguy72 just so you are aware of the difference between `SEARCH` and `FIND`, one is case sensitive and the other is not.  I did not see that change explained anywhere so thought it may be worth pointing out.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found out about that 2 weeks ago.  I had to work on a small project that required this: If C.Value Like "*date*" Or C.Value Like "*Date*" Then That turned out to be case sensitive too. Thanks for the help today.